# Encapsulate repeated assertions in a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

I have several integration tests where some of the assertions are the same. For maintainability concerns, I'd like to regroup the common assertions of each test under a unique function.

```
  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: "", password: "" } }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: @user.email, password: "password" } }
    .

  end
```

For instance, the

```
get login_path
assert_template 'sessions/new'
```

bit are repeated inside the two tests. How can I make this more maintainable?

Answer (score 0):

The part that you describe as "repeated" should not be asserted on each test. If the first test fails at asserting the template, then the other tests using the same assertion will also fail. This means you should extract that test logic into a single test, something like `test 'login rendered template'` and remove those `get` & `assert_template` from the other tests:

```
test "login rendered template" do
  get login_path
  assert_template 'sessions/new'
end

test "login with invalid information" do
  # template assertion already done in previous test
  post login_path, params: { session: { email: "", password: "" } }
  # [...]
end
```

This is an example of a bad practice in testing your app. A single test should make assertion(s) about a specific logic/feature and not be repeated. If you see pieces of code/assertions repeated in your test suite, it should probably be extracted to a single test.